# Update query to update records 'between' other records?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Sample table:

```
 N  ProductName          Cost          Type            TOTAL

 1  ProductX             3             Checker  
 2  Product0             5             TOY
 3  Product1             5             TOY
 4  Product2             8             TOY
```

Rows 2,3,4 Need Cost Of Type = Checker + current row cost into the TOTAL column. So row 2 would be 8, 3 would be 8 and 4 would be 11

```
 5  ProductZ             10            Checker         
 6  Product3             5             TOY
 7  Product4             9             TOY
 8  Product5             18            TOY
 9  Product6             25            TOY
```

Likewise, these need Cost of ProductZ added to their totals. So Row 6 would be 15, 7 would be 19, and so on.  They cannot go back and reference ProductY at row 1.

The datasets are not always the same, and there may be more "Checker" type items in the dataset.

When there's only one, it works really well, obviously.  But when there's more than one I have issues where the products total is wrong because it's using the wrong "Checker" value.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot do this in T-SQL given the front end restrictions.. so if it's not possible to iterate through the rows via some sort of query I'll have to rethink this.

Comment: Why don't you add a column Checker_Id which has a reference to the Product_Id that as 'main' product. Or else a many to many table if there is more then one checker.

Comment: Is it correct to describe this as "For any given row with a "TOY" in the TYPE, there may be some rows that have a lower value in column N and have the value "CHECKER" in Type.  If there are any rows with Checker, they will all have different values in N.  The highest one is the "Checker" that goes with the "TOY"?  That is, you're always interested in the "Highest" (by N) "Checker" that is less (by N) than any given "TOY"?  That's probably easy enough to do with a MERGE query that's available in 2008, confirm and someone will write it for you.  If not let me know how I missed the point.

Comment: n is auto number. Toy will always have higher n value than checker that needs to be used for calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this query works.

```
WITH toysAndCheckers AS
(
SELECT n AS toy, (SELECT top 1 lowerCheckers.n From sampleTable AS lowerCheckers
        WHERE lowerCheckers.N < theToys.N
        AND lowerCheckers.[type] = 'Checker'
        ORDER by n desc) AS matchingChecker

FROM sampleTable AS theToys
WHERE theToys.[type] = 'TOY'
),
toyCostAdjustments AS
(SELECT toy, cost AS checkerAdjustment
FROM toysAndCheckers 
JOIN sampleTable
    ON MatchingChecker = n
)       
MERGE sampleTable
USING
toyCostAdjustments
ON n = toy
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET total = cost + CheckerAdjustment
;
```

The first CTE, "toysAndCheckers", gets for each toy the N of the CHECKER row that is highest while still being lower than the TOY in question.   The second one just replaces the N of the checker with the cheker's cost.  Then you have a straightforward merge.  Assuming the N column is unique, you'll never have multiple matches.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
with Numbered as (
  select
    (select top (1) Cost from T as T2
     where T2.N <= T.N
       and T2.Type = 'Checker'
     order by N) as fv,
    *
  from T
)
  update Numbered set 
    TOTAL = Cost + fv
  where Type <> 'Checker';
```

You didn't say what TOTAL should be for the 'Checker' rows, so I left it NULL.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any way to do this my preferred way - in a set-based manner.

You can always resort to a cursor - it's not exactly high-performance or anything, but it works. If that's just a one-off, then you're fine. If you need to do this often, you might want to continue looking for a better solution:

```
-- declare a table variable for testing
DECLARE @sample TABLE (Num INT PRIMARY KEY, ProductName VARCHAR(50), Cost INT, ProdType VARCHAR(10), Total INT)

-- insert some data    
INSERT INTO @sample VALUES
    (1, 'ProductX', 3, 'Checker', NULL),
    (2, 'Product0', 5, 'TOY', NULL),
    (3, 'Product1', 5, 'TOY', NULL),
    (4, 'Product2', 8, 'TOY', NULL),
    (5, 'ProductZ', 10, 'Checker', NULL),
    (6, 'Product3', 5, 'TOY', NULL),
    (7, 'Product4', 9, 'TOY', NULL),
    (8, 'Product5', 18, 'TOY', NULL),
    (9, 'Product6', 25, 'TOY', NULL),
    (10, 'ProductY', 15, 'Checker', NULL),
    (11, 'Product7', 15, 'TOY', NULL),
    (12, 'Product8', 12, 'TOY', NULL),
    (13, 'Product9', 5, 'TOY', NULL)

-- declare the cursor, specify that we want to UDPATE the Total column   
DECLARE SampleCursor CURSOR KEYSET FOR
    SELECT Cost, Prodtype
    FROM @sample
    ORDER BY Num
    FOR UPDATE OF Total

-- declare and initialize variables    
DECLARE @Cost INT, @LastCheckerCost INT, @ProdType VARCHAR(10)

SET @LastCheckerCost = 0

-- open cursor and iterate over data set    
OPEN SampleCursor 

FETCH NEXT FROM SampleCursor INTO @Cost, @ProdType

-- while we have data......  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    -- if we have a "Checker" row -> remember that value for later
    IF @ProdType = 'Checker'
        SET @LastCheckerCost = @Cost

    ELSE 
        -- if we have a "normal" row, update the Total column
        UPDATE @sample
        SET Total = @LastCheckerCost + @Cost
        WHERE CURRENT OF SampleCursor

    -- get next set of data    
    FETCH NEXT FROM SampleCursor INTO @Cost, @ProdType
END

-- close and clean up cursor
CLOSE SampleCursor 
DEALLOCATE SampleCursor

-- inspect results
SELECT * FROM @Sample
```